# delete older folder with similar name using python

Tags: python

I need to iterate over a folder tree.  I have to check each subfolder, which looks like this:

```
moduleA-111-date
moduleA-112-date
moduleA-113-date
moduleB-111-date
moduleB-112-date
etc.
```

I figured out how to iterate over a folder tree.  I can also use **stat** with **mtime** to get the date of the folder which seems easier than parsing the name of the date.

How do I single out modules with the same prefix (such as "moduleA") and  compare their **mtime**'s so I can delete the oldest?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please follow http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve when you post.  We need a clear description of the problem, including your present code, the incorrect operation, and what you *want* to happen.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have no code, I assume that you're looking for design help.  I'd lead my students to something like:

```
Make a list of the names
From each name, find the prefix, such as "moduleA.  Put those in a set.
For each prefix in the set
    Find all names with that prefix; put these in a temporary list
    Sort this list.
    For each file in this list *except* the last (newest)
        delete the file
```

Does this get you moving?

Comment: it does, I was thinking along that line but it seemed "complicated", I tried playing around with generators to make the code more "pretty".
I'll write some code and update how it goes.

Comment: I have a few lines of code in.. I got to the part where I'm a specific point at the tree where I need to start "processing", for now I'm printing:
 for item in next(listDir):
  print item

tekiya1
file1.txt
folder3
folder2
file2.txt
folder1
file3.txt

from here I will need to leave only the folders (still working on that) and the put the folder in a set (simple constructor should do), then how do I sort by prefix?  regex? that's kinda advanced for me

your help is most appreciated.

Comment: <list_name>.sort will sort a list of strings.  Since the prefix is in front and fixed-length, that should do it.

Comment: took me some time but I managed to do some progress, this is the actual output I'm getting from the sorted list:
['anotherfile', 'file1', 'folder1', 'folder2', 'folder3', 'stamfile']

Seems I'm having trouble explaining myself.. in the above example I have some unique folder names and then I have folder1/2/3 - my goal is for folder1/2/3 check which is the newest one and delete the others - I know how to do that, what I don't know is how do I single folder1/2/3 out from the rest of the list, or in other words, for all folders like "folder" ... run a function that checks what i described above.

Comment: Please edit your original description to contain the updates to the problem description.  Look up the string processing functions for the various ways to identify strings by content.  The easiest is the "in" operator, such as /// if "folder" in file_name:

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting the code (answer) here, I suppose my question wasn't clear since I'm getting minus signs but anyway the solution wasn't as straight forward as I thought, I'm sure the code could use some fine tuning but it get's the job done.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os
import sys
import fnmatch
import glob
import re
import shutil


##########################################################################################################
#Remove the directory
def remove(path):

    try:
        shutil.rmtree(path)
        print "Deleted : %s" % path
    except OSError:
        print OSError
        print "Unable to remove folder: %s" % path

##########################################################################################################
#This function will look for the .sh files in a given path and returns them as a list.
def searchTreeForSh(path):

    full_path = path+'*.sh'
    listOfFolders = glob.glob(full_path)
    return listOfFolders

##########################################################################################################
#Gets the full path to files containig .sh and returns a list of folder names (prefix) to be acted upon.
#listOfScripts is a list of full paths to .sh file
#dirname is the value that holds the root directory where listOfScripts is operating in
def getFolderNames(listOfScripts):

    listOfFolders = []
    folderNames = []

    for foldername in listOfScripts:
        listOfFolders.append(os.path.splitext(foldername)[0])

    for folders in listOfFolders:
        folder = folders.split('/')
        foldersLen=len(folder)
        folderNames.append(folder[foldersLen-1])

    folderNames.sort()
    return folderNames

##########################################################################################################

def minmax(items):
    return max(items)
##########################################################################################################
#This function will check the latest entry in the tuple provided, and will then send "everything" to the remove function except that last entry
def sortBeforeDelete(statDir, t):

    count = 0

    tuple(statDir)

    timeNotToDelete = minmax(statDir)

    for ff in t:
        if t[count][1] == timeNotToDelete:
            count += 1
            continue
        else:
            remove(t[count][0])
            count += 1

##########################################################################################################
#A loop to run over the fullpath which is broken into items (see os.listdir above), elemenates the .sh and the .txt files, leaves only folder names, then matches it to one of the
#name in the "folders" variable

def coolFunction(folderNames, path):

    localPath = os.listdir(path)

    for folder in folderNames:

        t = () # a tuple to act as sort of a dict, it will hold the folder name and it's equivalent st_mtime
        statDir = [] # a list that will hold the st_mtime for all the folder names in subDirList

        for item in localPath:
            if os.path.isdir(path + item) == True:
                if re.search(folder, item):
                    mtime = os.stat(path + '/' + item)
                    statDir.append(mtime.st_mtime)
                    t = t + ((path + item,mtime.st_mtime),)# the "," outside the perenthasis is how to make t be a list of lists and not set the elements one after theother.

        if t == ():continue

        sortBeforeDelete(statDir, t)

##########################################################################################################

def main(path):
    dirs = os.listdir(path)
    for component in dirs:
        if os.path.isdir(component) == True:
            newPath = path + '/' + component + '/'
            listOfFolders= searchTreeForSh(newPath)
            folderNames = getFolderNames(listOfFolders)
            coolFunction(folderNames, newPath)


##########################################################################################################


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv[1])
```